# Trying to find a way to keep up to date MIR'ed directory of 7 days worth of info

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, robocopy

I am trying to use Robocopy (Win10) to maintain a directory of 7 days worth of music that will 'age out', with the 8th prior day being deleted.  I run this script nightly.

I have tried this, simply:

```
robocopy c:\music c:\music7 /MIR /MAXAGE:7 /S
```

Initial copy works great; what happens though is files that are 8 days old (or older) are not 'purged' from music7 directory on the 8th day.  Am I missing a parameter in `robocopy` to cull those?

You can repro this also by running the first command:

```
robocopy c:\music c:\music7 /MIR /MAXAGE:7
```

and then re-running altering the MAXAGE to lower

```
robocopy c:\music c:\music7 /MIR /MAXAGE:2
```

and note that days 3-7 content are not removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misconception about the purge logic (`/purge`) implied by the `/mir` option:

Only files that no longer *exist* in the *source* directory are also removed from the destination directory, which is unrelated to the `/maxage:<N>` option.

`/maxage:<N>` only restricts which of the existing source files are copied, by when they were last modified.
It does *not* mean that older files are automatically *removed* from the destination directory.

Therefore, assuming that you want to keep older files around in the *source* folder and only purge them from the *destination* folder:

- Run `robocopy c:\music c:\music7 /mir /maxage:7`, as before, which will copy only the last 7 days' worth of file to the destination folder.

  - As an aside: no need for option `/s` (copy subdirs., except empty ones), because `/mir` implies `/e` (copy subdirs., including empty ones)
- Then use a different tool / shell, such as PowerShell, to remove older files from the *destination* folder:

```
$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7)
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath c:\Music7 |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutOffDate } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* what will be deleted; remove it to perform actual deletion.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the comments.  After additional research I was able to get what I was after staying in CMD using the ForFiles command in conjunction with Robocopy in a batch file.

Similar to these lines:

```
ForFiles /p "c:\music7" /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @path /Q /S"

ForFiles /p "c:\music7" /d -7 /c "cmd /c rd @path /Q"

Robocopy c:\music c:\music7 /MIR /MAXAGE:6
```

Things can get a little quirky since I can have some directories whose dates appear to be modified earlier or later than their files under them, so I can't just do a destructive RD /S; robocopy will add the files back on its run.

PS - For those curious, this methodology allows me to effectively emulate time based autoplaylists for Groove which doesn't support it natively like WMP or Zune did.  I can push the 7 days worth of songs into OneDrive\Music and filter on that in the player clients to play that subset of my collection.  Now I have a way to task scheduler automate the purge older than 7 days content.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

In powershell after your robocopy or a separate process

```
        Get-ChildItem -file -path C:\music ($_.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-8)) | remove-item
```

Comment: Your command is syntactically invalid - you're missing a `Where-Object` call.

Comment: Other than that, I think you're on the right track, except that you should add `-Recurse` and probably target `c:\music7`, not `c:\music`. (I didn't down-vote)